# How to calculate the Stern-Gerlach term from the charged spin one anti-symmetric field equation?

Tags: quantum-spin

How does one calculate the Stern-Gerlach term from the charged spin one anti-symmetric field equation?

I first denoted the following momentum operator $D_a=(i\hbar\partial_a-qA_a)$, and then I wrote down the anti-symmetric field
\begin{align}
\phi^a_{\ b}
=
D^a \psi_b
-
D_b \psi^a
\end{align}
and then computed its divergence
\begin{align}
D_a
\phi^a_{\ b}
&=&
D_a
\left(
D^a \psi^b
-
D_b \psi^a
\right)
\\&=&
D_aD^a \psi^b
-
D_aD_b \psi^a
\end{align}
Next I introduced a gauge term and the commutator
\begin{align}
D^a
\phi_a^{\ b}
&=&
D^aD_a \psi^b
+
[D_b,D_a] \psi^a
-
D_b D_a \psi^a
\end{align}
and then I set the gauge term to zero $D_a \psi^a = 0$. 
\begin{align}
D^a
\phi_a^{\ b}
&=&
D^aD_a \psi^b
+
[D_b,D_a] \psi^a
\end{align}
I assumed the commutator $[D_b,D_a]$ was the Stern-Gerlach term for Spin One particles, however I discovered
\begin{align}
[D_b,D_a]
\neq
i\hbar q(\partial_bA_a-\partial_aA_b) = i\hbar qF_{ba}
\end{align}
was not the Electromagnetic Field Tensor $F_{ba}$.

Does this suggest that Spin One charged particles cannot be written in a form similar to the Electromagnetic Field Tensor equations?

Comment: Why do you say that $[D_\mu,D_\nu]$ is not $F_{\mu\nu}$? That's, essentially, the *definition* of $F_{\mu\nu}$.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Sorry, but when I expanded $[D_\mu,D_\nu]$ I discovered terms that contained derivatives on the wave-function and I was puzzled on why they did not disappear.

Comment: Provided that $[A_\mu,A_\nu] = 0$, i.e. $A_\mu$ is the EM vector potential and not an arbitrary gauge field, $[D_\mu,D_\nu]$ has exactly the value $F_{\mu\nu} = \partial_\mu A_\nu - \partial_\nu A_\mu$ (constants omitted). How would you get a wavefunction into $[D_\mu,D_\nu]$ at all? It's an operator, not a wavefunction. There's just $\partial_mu$ and $A_\mu$ in there, and since $[\partial_\mu,\partial_nu] = 0$, all that remains from the commutator are the mixed $\partial_\mu A_\nu$ terms in $F_{\mu\nu}$.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Wow. I do not know what I was thinking the last time I wrote that commutator down, but when I did it a second time it worked. All of the derivatives on the wavefunction disappear. Thanks for the support.